# Using CreateQuery to get a parent object with its children collection

Tags: nhibernate, createquery

The question is to get all parents whose all children age is above a certain age.The expected output should also include the children list with their parent.

I have the following...

```
session.CreateQuery("select p, c from Parent as p left outer join p.Children as c where c.Age!= :age")
 .SetParameter("age", somevalue);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Initializing[ns.Parent #18]-failed to lazily initialize a collection
of role: ns.Children, no session or session was closed
```

This is my code:

```
class Parent {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}


class Child {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int Age{ get; set; }
   public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }   
}

  //the mapping

  public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
    {
        public ParentMap()
        {
            this.Id(t => t.Id);         
            this.HasMany(t => t.Child).Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }

    class ParentRepository : IParentRepository {

        public IEnumerable<Parent> GetAll()
        {

                using (var session = _factory.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.CreateQuery("select p, c from Parent as p left outer join       p.Children as c where c.Age!= :age")
                    .SetParameter("age", somevalue);

                    return result.Distinct().ToArray();
                }

        }
    }

//In a different class I call GetAll.
var data = parentRepository.GetAll();
//at the following line that i get the error. 
    IEnumerable<Contracts.Parent> parents = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ns.Parent>,        IEnumerable<Contracts.Parent>>(data.ToArray());
```

I use AutoMapper to map the object to another similar objects(Parent and Child). 
The Parent and the Child in the Contract namespace has exactly the same type of properties

Comment: As indicated by the error message, you are attempting to call `CreateQuery` with no open session. Please ensure you are not closing/disposing your session, or post the code where you call `CreateQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate and its `ISession` do require a *different* approach then `using` statement *(usually)*. What we do prefer is to have a `session` - to be opened as late as possible *(e.g. even some lazy techniques)* and keep it open *(if opened)* as long as possible.

In case of web applications, the most common approaches are *(see [Effective NHibernate Session management for web apps](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx))*

- Use BeginRequest/EndRequest to open/close the session. Handle the transaction with AOP – attributes. I am not sure but I think this is the case for the AutoTransaction facility of castle.
- To use Asp.Net MVC ActionFilters to Open/Close the session and the transaction.

If you are in a web environment, please check for example this: [session-per-web-global.cs](https://gist.github.com/jonathansewell/1220453). A snippet of that code:

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...     
    //Configure NHibernate and create a session factory for the application
    var nhibernateConiguration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
    nhibernateConiguration.Configure();
    SessionFactory = nhibernateConiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create NHibernate session for this request and bind it to the
    //NHibernate session context (configured as web context using HttpContext)
    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Detach the session from this web request
    var session = NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    session.Dispose();
}
```

Even if not in the web-request scenario, try to find out some ways how to handle the ISession, and keep it open over more operations... check:

[Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)